# I would like to change a direction of Qtablewidget From Right to left

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtablewidget

i need to make Qtablewidget start from Right to left which mean verticalHeader() on right side

```
    self.table = QTableWidget()
    self.table.setGeometry(0 , 0 , 700 , 700)
    self.table.setColumnCount(4)
    self.table.setRowCount(30)
    self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['يومى', 'الاسبوع' , 'الشهرى' , 'المادة'])
    self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> layoutDirection : Qt::LayoutDirection
>
> This property holds the default layout direction for this application
>
> On system start-up, the default layout direction depends on the application's language.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

class MyWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__()
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.table = QTableWidget(central_widget)
        self.table.setGeometry(0 , 0 , 700 , 700)
        self.table.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table.setRowCount(30)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['يومى1', 'الاسبوع2' , 'الشهرى3' , 'المادة4'])
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)           # <-------------------
    w = MyWin()
    w.resize(700, 700)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]